# React Mount/Unmount event

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have my router like this

```
<Route component={Home} exact path="/" />
<Route component={ChannelScreen} path="/channel/:channelId" />
```

Home and ChannelScreen component contain a Player component.
So when I change the page, a new Player is created each time. But the Player componentDidMount event is called before the componentWillUnmount. **The player component is recreated before destroying the other one**.

Shouldn't It launch componentWillUnmount before creating the new one ?

Comment: Lol, interesting :D

Comment: I don't know answer, but you can start research from this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/5eb3ab3522bd1d46fb4f8471c8207f1e0bc2cc25

Comment: Which version of react-router you have?

Comment: @croraf, last version: 4.1.1

Comment: It seem that using a <Switch> solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test and this is not true in general, componentWillUnmount is called before componentWillMount. You have some bug in your application.